Spring Batch 5 : Failing with Caused by: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'date' could not be parsed at index 0
Recently , I have migrated our application to java 17 with Spring 5.1.2 so Spring batch also got migrated from v4 to v5.
Did the necessary changes as mentioned in guide book.
However, During the first run , spring framework will start inserting data into batch tables properly but it fails with application level issue (some crt issue).
So, after correction of crt, If I tried to run the application then its failing with below error :
org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.util.Date] for value [date]
Caused by: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'date' could not be parsed at index 0
Below query is getting used in spring batch :
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/wiki/Spring-Batch-5.0-Migration-Guide?secureweb=Teams&secureweb=Teams&secureweb=Teams#column-change-in-batch_job_execution_params
SELECT JOB_EXECUTION_ID, PARAMETER_NAME, PARAMETER_TYPE, PARAMETER_VALUE, IDENTIFYING
FROM BDB_DBA.BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS
WHERE JOB_EXECUTION_ID = ?
Full stack trace :
2024-09-26 22:18:12,809 [main] (JdbcTemplate.java:721) DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL query
2024-09-26 22:18:12,810 [main] (JdbcTemplate.java:650) DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT JOB_EXECUTION_ID, PARAMETER_NAME, PARAMETER_TYPE, PARAMETER_VALUE, IDENTIFYING
FROM BDB_DBA.BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS
WHERE JOB_EXECUTION_ID = ?
]
2024-09-26 22:18:12,810 [main] (StatementCreatorUtils.java:237) TRACE org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 1, parameter value [0], value class [java.lang.Long], SQL type unknown
2024-09-26 22:18:13,058 [main] (TransactionAspectSupport.java:676) TRACE org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor - Completing transaction for [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.getLastJobExecution] after exception: org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.util.Date] for value [date]
2024-09-26 22:18:13,058 [main] (AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:893) DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Initiating transaction rollback
2024-09-26 22:18:13,058 [main] (DataSourceTransactionManager.java:349) DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Rolling back JDBC transaction on Connection [HikariProxyConnection@1130153977 wrapping oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@6c008c24]
2024-09-26 22:18:13,301 [main] (DataSourceUtils.java:243) DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Resetting isolation level of JDBC Connection [HikariProxyConnection@1130153977 wrapping oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@6c008c24] to 2
2024-09-26 22:18:13,544 [main] (DataSourceTransactionManager.java:393) DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Releasing JDBC Connection [HikariProxyConnection@1130153977 wrapping oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@6c008c24] after transaction
2024-09-26 22:18:13,549 [main] (Application.java:59) ERROR com.jpmorgan.multisource.matureassets.application.Application - Fatal Error
org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.util.Date] for value [date]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:47) ~[spring-core-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:182) ~[spring-core-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:165) ~[spring-core-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobExecutionDao.lambda$getJobParameters$2(JdbcJobExecutionDao.java:475) ~[spring-batch-core-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$RowCallbackHandlerResultSetExtractor.extractData(JdbcTemplate.java:1762) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:733) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:658) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:723) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:754) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:783) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:799) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobExecutionDao.getJobParameters(JdbcJobExecutionDao.java:484) ~[spring-batch-core-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobExecutionDao$JobExecutionRowMapper.mapRow(JdbcJobExecutionDao.java:510) ~[spring-batch-core-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobExecutionDao$JobExecutionRowMapper.mapRow(JdbcJobExecutionDao.java:495) ~[spring-batch-core-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:94) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:61) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:733) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:658) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:723) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:754) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:767) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:825) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobExecutionDao.getLastJobExecution(JdbcJobExecutionDao.java:342) ~[spring-batch-core-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.getLastJobExecution(SimpleJobRepository.java:303) ~[spring-batch-core-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:354) ~[spring-aop-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196) ~[spring-aop-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:379) ~[spring-tx-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:223) ~[spring-aop-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at jdk.proxy2.$Proxy35.getLastJobExecution(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:111) ~[spring-batch-core-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
Caused by: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'date' could not be parsed at index 0


image of BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS table :
enter image description here
not able to understand what is root cause , as we not updating anything manually. Spring batch framework takes care of everything.
For table creation :
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/main/spring-batch-core/src/main/resources/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-oracle.sql
It should properly work, even if the previous job is in Failed state
<bean id="jobRepository"
      class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceHikari"/>
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
    <property name="databaseType" value="oracle"/>
    <property name="tablePrefix" value="BATCH_"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jobLauncher"
          class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository"/>
    </bean>

 <bean id="taskExecutor"
          class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor" scope="job">
        <property name="queueCapacity" value="100"/>
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="30"/>
        <property name="corePoolSize" value="10"/>
    </bean>


Your exception message says Text 'date' could not be parsed at index 0. It sounds reasonable that date cannot be parsed as a date and/or time. So I guess you need to find out where and why your program is trying to do that. Aren’t there more lines to the stack trace? They should help.

That's the part did not understand, Its not application code , its the code from Spring batch , all the tables belongs to spring batch only

In the screenshot you shared, I see the value of the parameter runTime is the string literal date. This means the job was started with a parameter like runTime=date, which is obviously incorrect.
I recommend you to change the parameter's type from java.lang.String to java.time.LocalDate and pass a correct date value on startup.
Spring Batch already registers a LocalDate to/from String converter by default.

That said, I think Spring Batch should not fail with that exception. It should rather fail earlier with a more meaningful exception. There is a room for improvement here.
